# Copy specific files with a batch

Tags: powershell, batch-file

please help how can I do this.

- there is a **lot of folders**, which contains **a lot of PDF**.
- files have 0,1,2 or 3 version (version in file name 0,A, B or C. C is the highest(latest,which I need)

Example I have this files in C:\files (part from hundred files)

```
2911010_01_0_A4.pdf 
2911010_01_A_A4.pdf 
2911010_01_B_A4.pdf 
2911011_01_0_a3.pdf 
2911012_01_0_A4.pdf 
2911020_01_0_A4.pdf 
2911020_01_A_A4.pdf 
2911021_01_0_A4.pdf 
2911021_01_A_A4.pdf 
2911021_01_B_A4.pdf
```

From this files I need to copy this files (with a batch)

```
2911010_01_B_A4.pdf (becase B version is the highest)
2911011_01_0_a3.pdf (because there is only one version from this file)
2911012_01_0_A4.pdf (because there is only one version from this file)
2911020_01_A_A4.pdf (because A version is the highest)
2911021_01_B_A4.pdf (because B version is the highest)
```

Thanks for your helping !

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Your question isn't totally clear. You should state exactly what conditions where you want a file and/or folder copy instead of getting somebody else to work this out. I'd recommend reading this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Help implies a collaborative effort, your question as it stands appears more like you want us to perform all of the work. Please [edit] your question and submit the code you have written to perform the task according to your specifications above, but which has failed to work, and for which you require us to help you fix. Your version system appears to use alphanumeric characters in ascending order, so you should at least take a look at the `dir` command, which has options for sorting according to name. Please open a Command Prompt window, type `dir /?`, press the `[ENTER]` key, and read.

Comment: SO is not a script writing service mind you but you can start with something like [this](https://tio.run/##dY7PC4IwFMfv/hXvUKwgZVtB5CXt0qlrl6whujQYObZJhe1vNyEjEX2Hd/i8748niwdXOudC1HWAHLohBBPMMGGYhStPplfownAI7nqQfO3xsgvpQCbFo7BXRMmQkowq/y@hAFwtxc0AitQ2uiN4gwPNZKooJVQnxTP@PPv@ITZJPpuwBbpEabW2rNnUMjT3jrEouf35dKEMuFIVkivzamPa2xSqCfP2LdJc8KTRilgbILauPw).For the inputs you've given, it returns the filenames you need to copy.

Comment: Thx Lieven,I was able with this help to done the job ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With PowerShell, you can use `Group-Object` to group files based on the name without the `0`/`A`/`B`/`C` version part, then simply sort the resulting groups (because luckily, `0`,`A`,`B`,`C` already corresponds to alphabetic ordering) and pick the last one from each:

```
# Gather latest version of each file
$filesToCopy = Get-ChildItem C:\files -Filter *.pdf |Group-Object {$_ -replace '[0ABC]_(..)(?=\.)','_$1'} |ForEach-Object {
  $_.Group |Sort-Object |Select-Object -Last 1
}

# Copy resulting files
$filesToCopy |Copy-Item -Destination C:\target
```

Comment: lol - added some counterweight :). The solution uses the same reasoning I had but slightly different order in the pipeline. Sure nice to be validated, I wasn't sure.

Comment: Given the comments from four different members, perhaps someone felt that what you've done, is open the door to more off topic questions. In addition, if they were truly looking for help, most likely for a basis upon where to start their task, your answer does not do that. It simply provides some code, and doesn't even tell the OP which of their tags it is relevant to.

Comment: Thx, this is working (in my version I've exported result to a text file (maybe some manager want to check result daily....) But with your "shorter" code do the same ! Thx for your work !